# Is "dharmosmat kuladaivatam" from the Shastras?

Tags: identification-request

*Dharmosmat Kuladaivatam* (translated by the source as, "Charity, Our Household Divinity") is the motto of Malayala Manorama, a leading Malayalam Newspaper.

[image: The Malayala Manorama insignia, with the phrase "Dharmosmat Kuladaivatam" in Malayalam script.]

Is this phrase from a Hindu text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The motto of *Malayala Manorama* is taken from the motto of the Travancore Royal family. It is inspired from the Mahabharata.

The insignia of the newspaper is a contribution from Shree Moolam Thirunal, then king of Travancore towards the newspaper. The lines "Dharmosmat Kuladaivatam" is the part of Travancore royal family emblem which is also the motto of Travancore royal family.

[image: Emblem of Travancore Royal family with two elephants and a conch]

From page 36 [*Kandathil Varghese Mappilai*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.231058/page/n35), a monologue by C.J Roy

> The insignia which accompanies the name Malayala Manorama was a contribution 
>   from Sree Moolam Thirunal, the then king of Travancore. Beneath it was the inscription dharmo' smat kuladaivatam which means Charity our- Household Divinity.

From page 45 of the same book,

> **With the Mahabharata aphorism dharmo' smat kuladaivatam** as the declared motto of his newspaper, Varghese Mappilai was particular that Malayala Manorama should be 
>   deeply rooted in Indian culture that visualised a unified human 
>   race devoid of differences in the name of caste, creed and region.

Mahabharata speaks of Dharma in great detail. There are two parvas Anushasana parva and Shanti Parva dedicated for explaining duties to Yudhishtira by Bhishma.

About charity, see [SECTION CXXXVII of Anushasanika Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b102.htm). Bhishma speaks of many kings and sages who ascended to heaven by performing charity.

Comment: Can you add Sanskrit text for clarity? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Sanskrit text for which verse @srimannarayanakv ?

Comment: You had stated - With the Mahabharata aphorism dharmo' smat kuladaivatam as the declared motto of his newspaper,  -. Mahabharata aphorism's text please @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @srimannarayanakv The Mahabharata aphorism is Dharmosmat kuladaivatam which is the motto of Travancore royal family and Malayala manorama.

Comment: I want full verse from Mahabharata please @Sarvabhouma

Comment: The verse is not directly from the Mahabharata. It is inspired from Mahabharata aphorism which says charity is a great deed. Charity is taken as their household practice by Travancore royal family. That is why it is said "Charity is _our_ household divinity".

Comment: The OP was interested in base of this motor from scriptures? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Read complete answer @srimannarayanakv I believe Mahabharata is also a scripture. Mahabharata also speaks of charity. I also linked specific chapter where  charity is talked about. The question asked whether it was present in scriptures or not. The answer is "It is inspired from scriptures".

Comment: Thank you, it was very informative. Isn't it wonderful that a Christian, Varghese Mappilai, used a Dharmic phrase for the motto of his paper?

Comment: @AravindSuresh Yes. Varghese Mappilai had a huge respect towards Indian culture and values. He had preceptors who were Brahmins and he believed in unity of all Indians irrespective of caste, creed, religion.